# Mudar CSS ao rolar a página

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estava querendo saber como trocar o CSS de uma página após ela receber um scrolling para fora de seu local padrão.

Um exemplo de um site que utiliza isso é o Deviantart.

Aquele menu de **TODAY BROWSEWHAT’S HOTUNDISCOVEREDDAILY DEVIATIONS** de repente fica fixado depois que a página sofre um scrolling.

Alguém sabe me dar um exemplo de como reproduzir isso para usar em meus websites?

*OBS: Eu infelizmente não sei se isso é CSS ou Javascript, se for possível, alguém pode corrigir a minha pergunta.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso utilizando um `if/else` juntamente com o `scrollTop()` do jQuery, como no exemplo deste código abaixo:

```js
// O código abaixo deverá ser implementado dentro de uma tag <script> caso implementada no código HTML
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 50) {
    $('.randomClass')
      .css({
        'background-color': 'tomato',
        'position': 'fixed'
      });
  } else {
    $('.randomClass')
      .css({
        'background-color': 'burlywood',
        'position': 'inherit'
      });
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
    height: 900px;
    position:relative;
}
.randomClass {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<!-- A Biblioteca jQuery abaixo deve ser implementada dentro do <head> do seu site/aplicação -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="randomClass"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso é feito via CSS, adiciona o propriedade position: fixed; ao elemento.

Comment: Diego podes completar a resposta com um exemplo?